# asp-action in ASP.NET Core 3.1 doesn't work with endpoint routing

Tags: asp.net-core

I created a controller with two action Index and CustomVariable

```cs
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Result", new Result { Controller = nameof(HomeController), Action = nameof(Index) });
    }

    public ViewResult CustomVariable(string id)
    {
        Result r = new Result { Controller = nameof(HomeController), Action = nameof(CustomVariable) };
        r.Data["id"] = /*RouteData.Values["id"];*/ id ?? "<noValue>";
        r.Data["catchall"] = RouteData.Values["catchall"];
        return View("Result", r);
    }
}
```

and created a view for displaying the results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Routing </title>
    <link rel=" stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css"/>

</head>
<body class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered  ">
        <tr><th>Controlle:</th><td>@Model.Controller</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Action:</th><td>@Model.Action</td></tr>
        @foreach (string key in Model.Data.Keys)
        {
            <tr><th>@key :</th><td>@Model.Data[key]</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
    <a asp-action="CustomVariable">this is an outgoing URL</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

In `Startup` I define two endpoints as shown below:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name:"NewRoute",
      pattern: "App/Do{action}",
     defaults: new {Controller="Home"}
    );
  
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern :"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}";
});
```

When I click on the URL, I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
>
> Matches:
>
> UrlsAndRoutes.Controllers.HomeController.Index (UrlsAndRoutes)
> UrlsAndRoutes.Controllers.HomeController.CustomVariable (UrlsAndRoutes)

But it works with attribute routing

Comment: Instead of `asp-action` could you try this: `href="@Url.RouteUrl("NewRoute", new { action = "CustomVariable" })"`.

Comment: I try that, same Error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I test your code,and delete the following code it can work:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name:"NewRoute",
      pattern: "App/Do{action}",
     defaults: new {Controller="Home"}
    );
```

or you can change it to:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name:"NewRoute",
          pattern: "Home/{action}",
         defaults: new {Controller="Home"}
        );
```

or you can use href="../ControllerName/ActionName" rather than asp-action,@Url.Action

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem.
Your pattern is invalid because using "Do{action}" can't be matched with any action in the `HomeController` so to preserve the pattern you want, i suggest to do the following instead:

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "NewRoute",
    pattern: "App/Do/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
```

Comment: yes, that way works but I want to use DO as a static word before my action, problem is why endpoints Routing can not recognize asp-action but in the Attribute route like `[Route("App/Do{action}")]` works perfectly

Comment: @Ehsan Of course it works with attribute routing because in attribute routing you can set unique routes explicitly while with endpoint routing it goes by pattern.

P.S, The accepted answer changes your route to this `/Home/CustomVariable` which defeats the whole purpose of the `NewRoute`.